# python http serving not close connections, connections are opened in OS in WAIT_TIME state

Tags: python, python-3.x, http, sockets

This is a part of my code, In this code I want to handle http request. this is sample. I want to get http POST request, then send a response to sender, after that I want to close connection. but as you can see in commented lines, after test every method and function but not working. connections still opened and in OS, connection going to WAIT_TIME state. after some seconds, limitation of OS got full and not allow to receive any new connections. how can I close income connections without going to WAIT_TIME state? why connection not close correctly?

```
class LoadBalancerHandler(http.server.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler):

def do_POST(self):
    request_body = self.rfile.read(int(self.headers['Content-Length']))
    # # self.wfile.flush()
    # # if response_main:
    # # self.wfile.write(response_main.read())
    # self.close_connection = True
    # self.ThreadedHTTPServer.allow_reuse_address = True
    # # self.server.server_close()
    # # self.server.server_close(self.wfile)
    # self.server.allow_reuse_address = True
    self.send_response(code=200)
    self.end_headers()
    self.close_connection = Trues
    # self.wfile.write(response.content)
    self.wfile.write(b"Response content")
    # Close the incoming connection
    try:
        self.request.shutdown(socket.SHUT_RDWR)
    except:
        self.request.close()

    # self.flush_headers()
    # self.wfile.close()
    # self.server.server_close()
    # self.server.server_activate()
    # elf.server.finish_request(self.request,self.client_address)
    # Return the response from the first destination to the sender
    # self.send_response(code=200)
    # self.end_headers()
    # self.flush_headers()
    # self.wfile.write(b"Response content")
    # self.wfile.flush()
    # self.request.shutdown(socket.SHUT_RDWR)
    # self.request.close()
    # self.server.finish_request(self.request, client_address=self.client_address)
    # self.finish()
    #self.connection.close()
    # self.server.shutdown()
    # self.server.server_close()
    # if response_main:
    # self.wfile.write(response_main.read())
    # self.request.close()
    # self.request.shutdown(socket.SHUT_RDWR)

if __name__ == "__main__":
# Start the load balancer to listen on port 8000
with socketserver.TCPServer(("", PORT), LoadBalancerHandler,False) as httpd:
    logging.info("Load balancer serving at port %d", PORT)
    print("Load balancer serving at port", PORT)
    httpd.allow_reuse_address = True
    httpd.serve_forever()
```